# Angular - Is this an app issue or a deployment issue?

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, angular-cli

I'm building a personal website using Angular(v4+). I'm aware it's a little excessive of a framework for just a simple website. Angular is a framework I'd really like to get better with so that's why I'm using it. Throughout development, I used `ng serve` to test. The app builds with `ng build` or `ng build --prod` successfully. Even `ng serve --prod` works. However, when I want to test the app on the compiled files in the dist folder, only part of my app works ( I get runtime errors in my console, as well as the assets are a bit off where the pictures don't load).

Now, I read somewhere else on StackOverflow that the dist folder for angular builds are solely for serving/deploying and that opening the index.html file won't give you the correct results (even with `ng build --bh .`). Am I correct in saying this?

So that's my question: Is my angular build faulty or am I just failing to deploy it to the server correctly? (Azure web app in my case)

Thanks much!

Comment: I don't have much experience in running Angular app without Express. With Express, I've never had errors (neither with http-server which sometimes I used to test my application) but looks like some problems appear if we try to open `index.html` directly, as we can see in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960446/error-after-building-angular4-project-for-production/47960878#47960878.

But at the same time, I've created a simple Angular application with `ng new project-name`, built with `ng build --prod --base-href ./` and opened `index.html` directly in the browser - it works.

Answer (score 0):

How are you serving your files?

Look in to http-server on npm for a portable web server.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer, since it's for clarification. (and you have more than enough reputation to post comments)

Comment: @DavidMakogon Thanks for contributing to the discussion. Your comment really helped advance the conversation.